# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Tags: android, database, listview, android-contacts

I'm trying to load contact information and display it using a list view. But I get an error instead.

My code:

```
public class Sync extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

//cursor loader
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

List<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

private static final String DisplayName="";
private static final String Given="";
private static final String Family="";
private static final  String NickName="";
private static final String HomePhone="";
private static final  String MobilePhone="";
private static final String WorkPhone="";
private static final String HomeEmail="";
private static final String WorkEmail="";
private static final String CompanyName="";
private static final String Title="";
ArrayList<String> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    //ContactHoldObject co;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    //ListView contactView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllContacts().execute();

}

  class LoadAllContacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Sync.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading list of training centers. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * getting All contacts
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            Uri contactsUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        // Querying the table ContactsContract.Contacts to retrieve all the contacts
        Cursor contactsCursor = getContentResolver().query(contactsUri, null, null, null,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC ");
       // ContactHoldObject.contactinfo =new ContactInfo[contactsCursor.getCount()];
        //co=new ContactHoldObject();


        if(contactsCursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                long contactId = contactsCursor.getLong(contactsCursor.getColumnIndex("_ID"));

                Uri dataUri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

             // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Cursor dataCursor = getContentResolver().query(dataUri, null,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID + "=" +    contactId,
                        null, null);


                String displayName="";
                String given="";
                String family="";
                String nickName="";
                String homePhone="";
                String mobilePhone="";
                String workPhone="";
                String homeEmail="";
                String workEmail="";
                String companyName="";
                String title="";

               displayName=dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
               //contactView.
               map.put(DisplayName, displayName);

                if(dataCursor.moveToFirst()){

                    String whereName = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID + " = " + contactId; 
                    String[] whereNameParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE };
                    Cursor nameCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, null, whereName, whereNameParams, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME);
                    while (nameCur.moveToNext()) {
                        if(nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME)) != null 
                                && !nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME)).equals("")){
                            given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));  
                        }else{
                            given="No firstname";
                        }
                        map.put(Given, given);
                        /*given = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
                        family = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
                        displayName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME ));
                        String string = nameCur.getString(nameCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DATA13));*/

                        /*System.out.println("Name: " + given + " Family: " +  family + " Displayname: "  + display + "MIDDLE_NAME"+MIDDLE_NAME+"PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME"+PHONETIC_FAMILY_NAME+" PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME:  "+PHONETIC_MIDDLE_NAME+"PREFIX   :"+PREFIX+  "SUFFIX  :" +SUFFIX+"DATA1::  "+DATA1+ "DATA1  :"+DATA1);*/
                    }nameCur.close();
                    do{

                        // Getting NickName
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Nickname.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                            nickName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                        //System.out.println("nickName "+nickName);
                        // Getting Phone numbers
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME :
                                homePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE :
                                mobilePhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK :
                                workPhone = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                break;
                            }
                        }


                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE ) ) {
                            switch(dataCursor.getInt(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data2"))){
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_HOME :
                                homeEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                break;
                            case ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE_WORK :
                                workEmail = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        // Getting Organization details
                        if(dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("mimetype")).equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Organization.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
                            companyName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data1"));
                            title = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("data4"));
                        }



                    }while(dataCursor.moveToNext());
                    String details = "";
                    String email=" ";
                    // Concatenating various information to single s
                    if(homePhone != null && !homePhone.equals("") )
                        details = "HomePhone : " + homePhone + "\n";
                    if(mobilePhone != null && !mobilePhone.equals("") )
                        details += "MobilePhone : " + mobilePhone + "\n";
                    if(workPhone != null && !workPhone.equals("") )
                        details += "WorkPhone : " + workPhone + "\n";
                    if(nickName != null && !nickName.equals("") )
                        details += "NickName : " + nickName + "\n";
                    if(homeEmail != null && !homeEmail.equals("") ){
                        details += homeEmail + "\n";
                        email=homeEmail;
                    }
                    if(workEmail != null && !workEmail.equals("") ){
                        details += workEmail + "\n";
                        email=workEmail;
                    }
                    if(companyName != null && !companyName.equals("") )
                        details += "CompanyName : " + companyName + "\n";
                    if(title != null && !title.equals("") )
                        details += "Title : " + title + "\n";

                    if(details!= null && !details.equals("") ){
                       // System.out.println(given+"\n"+details);


                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                        map.put(Family, family);
                        map.put(NickName, nickName);
                        map.put(HomePhone, homePhone);
                        map.put(WorkPhone, workPhone);
                        map.put(HomeEmail, homeEmail);
                        map.put(MobilePhone, mobilePhone);
                        map.put(WorkEmail, workEmail);
                        map.put(CompanyName, companyName);
                        map.put(Title, title);

                        //addContacts(given,email);
                    }
                }dataCursor.close();
                contactList.add(map);
                list = new ArrayList<String>(map.values());  }while(contactsCursor.moveToNext());




            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            }contactsCursor.close();

        return null;


    }
        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Sync.this, contactList,
                            R.layout.trackrow, new String[] {
                                    DisplayName},
                            new int[] { R.id.textName });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                }
            });

        }
        //return "success";
}
  @Override
  protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
      Map<String,String> item =  (Map<String, String>) l.getItemAtPosition(position); 

  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override // Creation du menu contextuel
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Action");
    menu.add(0,100,0,"Call");
    menu.add(0,200,1,"More details");
    menu.add(0, 300, 3, "Localisation");
    menu.add(0,400,2,"send mail");
    menu.add(0,500,4,"add comment");
    menu.add(0,600,5,"view comments");
    menu.add(0,700,5,"Link WebSite");
}

@Override // Selection d'un item du menu contextuel
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}

     }
```

Here's the error that shows up in logcat:

```
android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 7
```

It's probably a silly mistake, but I haven't been able to figure it out!

Comment: Which line of your code does LogCat say is producing the error?  A cursor with size 7 has incides 0-6 available, and your code is asking for index -1.  Find the line that LogCat says is producing the error and find out where the -1 comes from and you'll be in good (or at least better) shape.

Comment: Before retrieving `displayName` from dataCursor, try using `dataCursor.moveToFirst()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you call

```
displayName=dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
```

before

```
dataCursor.moveToFirst();
```

the cursor is therefore positioned at -1, which causes the Exception.